# Force Image module to regenerate thumbs

Tags: 6, media

I am using the [Image](http://drupal.org/project/image) module along with ImageGallery to make galleries in Drupal 6. I now have some 'holes' in my gallery where Image can't find the thumbnails, so they need to be regenerated. How do I force that to happen? Have tried clearing caches and running update.php, but I still have the holes. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest way is to just go to the ImageCache Styles page and re-save the style. Don't make any changes just hit save.

You could also just delete all the thumbnails out of the image_styles folder in your files/ directory.